# how to override the header with-in specific scenario in Karate

Tags: karate

I have configured the headers like below in the Background section and which works well.

```
* configure headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',userName : '#("TestUser" + randomNumber)',Accept : 'application/json'}
```

Now, for one of the scenario, I need to set the Accept header to application/xml and I tried below way but it does not work and in the console logs I see the Accept header as the same value configured in the background section.

```
* header Accept = 'application/xml'
```

How to override the accept header value from json to xml for one of the scenario.